# how to launch java file program with processbuilder?

Tags: java

here i'm trying to launch a java program inside another java program.
after some search in the forum i found some clues but my code launches only .exe file and not .java file why?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Mana
{
public static void main(String args[])
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
try
{
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" D:\\NetBeansProjects\\GetIPAddress\\dist\\GetIPAddress.jar");
}
catch(IOException e1) {System.out.println(e1);}
}
}
```

Comment: You can edit the question or leave comments to provide additional information. Please do not create answers that don't answer a question.

Answer (score 3):

for java file you must run javaw.exe(not java, because java.exe shows new console window) from jre:

`Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaw -jar D:\\NetBeansProjects\\GetIPAddress\\dist\\GetIPAddress.jar");`

Comment: Thank you, i try this with eclipse, i have the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to use 3rd party library, you can use:

http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/JavaProcessBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like you have several problems.

First, to call a java program as a jar file, you need to have the jar file. Your question first looked like you already had one (producted by Netbeans). So try this:

```
java -jar D:\NetBeansProjects\GetIPAddress\dist\GetIPAddress.jar
```

in a console window (cmd.exe on Windows). If this works, then your call as given by Sergey should work too. If it does not work, then you have to look at how to create this jar file.

Comment: OK, i have the jar file and i try your example.

Comment: Thank you i try your example with:

java -jar D:\NetBeansProjects\GetIPAddress\dist\GetIPAddress.jar

but now i don't have the error message, it's like it runs without any default but i don't see the output of my jar file.

there is just : run:BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

And nothing happens.

Comment: Did you do this on a command prompt, or from Netbeans? Do it from the Windows Command prompt.